# Как организовать структуру проекта, совмещающего в себе использование composer и npm / bower?

Tags: php, javascript, npm, composer, bower

Суть такова. Есть некий проект, который собирается при помощи `composer`. Основной движок проекта - `Phalcon (php framework)`. В его корне есть файл `composer.json`, в котором подключены всякие пакеты из тех или иных мест, а также 3 папки, `apps`, где живет `Phalcon`, и `public`, где живут необходимые для фронтенда вещи, плюс `index.php`, который инициализирует работу фреймворка. Третья папка: `vendor`, где живут подключенные через composer пакеты.

```
├── apps
│   ├── backend
│   └── frontend
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── public
│   ├── css
│   ├── index.php
│   └── js
└── vendor
    ├── autoload.php
    ├── ...
```

*Важно: веб-сервер смотрит прямиком на папку `public`, так что веб-браузер может видеть файлы только в ее пределах, таким образом подключать какой-нибудь `JQuery` через `composer` смысла нет, его файлы попадут в папку `vendor`, веб-браузеру не видимую.*

При всем при этом хочется использовать некий менеджер пакетов и для всяческих `Bootstrap`, `JQuery` и множества других js-библиотек, для того, чтобы и подгружать их в случае необходимости автоматически, и вообще как бы так правильно. Встает вопрос, как именно это сделать. Я вижу три пути:

1. Использовать composer, потом запускать что-то вроде `Gulp` и копировать нужные файлы из vendor в `public/js` или куда еще понадобится.
2. Использовать `npm`, инициализируя его прямо в папке `public`, и подключать скачанные им вещи из его папки, `npm_modules`.
3. использовать `npm`, но инициализируя его в корневой папке проекта, через него иницализировать `Bower` в папке `public` и опять же подключать скачанные им вещи из его папки, `bower_components`.

Или вместо 2 и 3 пункта (предпочтительнее третий, так как `Bower` не тянет за собой все зависимости пакетов, в отличии, если делать это через `npm`) использовать их смесь с 1 пунктом, инициализируя `npm` / `bower` в корне проекта и потом через `Gulp` или что-то подобное подтягивая в `public/js` нужные файлы?

Comment: http://gulpjs.com/,https://webpack.js.org/,https://gruntjs.com/  посмотрите на эти библиотеки они могут помоч с данной проблемой. Они позволят проводить сборку js/css

Comment: @E_p да я собственно про одну из них прямо в вопросе пишу, у меня на другом немного акцент - как наиболее верно их использовать, и есть ли вообще смысл, вместо того, чтобы подключать файлы просто напрямую из папок пакетных менеджеров, инициализированных прямо в public.

Comment: Всё зависит от цели. Если у вас много работы делаeться через js, tо использовать например `webpack` для сборки очень удобно. На выходе один **js** и один **css** файл, что так же ускоряет загрузку и решает проблему с кешированием. Но это дабовляет один шаг к деплою. Т. е. просто залить на сервер не получиться, надо сначала билд сделать (сборку на сервере не советую, нечего лишние ненужные библиотеки и программы там держать). Я пользовался `webpack` для сборки одного проекта, очень удобно.

Comment: ПС: Использовал `grunt` + `webpack` управлял `webpack` через `grunt`. Еще одно приемущество, можно разбить фронтенд HTML на темплейты, для более простой работы и собирать их в конечные файлы во время билда.

Comment: "разбить фронтенд HTML на темплейты, для более простой работы и собирать их в конечные файлы во время билда" - ну, это у меня делает фреймворк. А по поводу остального да, понятно что удобно, но хочется услышать обоснованный отказ именно от совсем простых вариантов, которые я в вопросе озвучил. Пока что вижу только один момент - удобно собрать все в один файл и тем самым решить вопрос с размером кода ну и с кешированием.

Comment: А других сильно и нету, только автомотизация. Как я уже сказал если нет необходимости на сервер node/npm держать не надо, желательно иметь build окружение(свой лаптоп). Т.е. если у вас мало js и не предвидеться много то можно и без гемороя.  А так я бы просто добавил package.json в корне. Потом использовал бы `gulp`/`grunt` для копирования нужных файлов с нужными именами в `public`.

Comment: @E_p кстати, а почему не чистый webpack, а grunt + webpack?

Comment: Grunt управлять разными конфигурациям для  dev   и production подчищает папки,  запускает веб сервер для тестирования, делает авто перегрузку при изменении файла. Ещё пару мелочей. Но правильный ответ: "Так повелось"